# Avalon Dock Float Window - ShowInTaskBar

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, avalondock

I am using AvalonDock in a PRISM based WPF application. My Document Panes have the ability to float (CanFloat = "true"). But the floating windows are not shown in TaskBar. Is there any way that I can make it available in TaskBar (ShowTaskBar = "true").

I tried traversing the VisualTree to get the root Window to set this property. But it is being modified in their source code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved it in this way,

```
dockingManager.FloatingWindows.ToList().ForEach(window =>
            {
                window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            });
```